# Particle Systems not working at all (2.79 and 2.8)

Tags: particles

The other day I was working on a render for one of my projects when I decided that it would be a good idea to add some particles.

I clicked the "new" button on the particle tab and to my surprise, nothing appeared. I tried playing with the settings but nothing happened still. I decided to try in blender 2.8 and I received the same results.

[image]

Only one particle appeared on the object even though the particle number was set to a thousand. Not a single setting seems to be working for me.

Here are some pictures of the settings tab in case I might have missed something: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Set the Start and the End to 0.

Comment: Try to play animation e.g. until frame 50